# PHP цикл while

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Имеется такой код:

```
// Выборка схожих значений
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY region ORDER BY  region",$db);
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);

// Выборка схожих не схожих значений
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users ORDER BY region" ,$db);

// Цикл
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

mysql_close($db);
```

Короче смысл такой что к этому файлу идет Ajax обращение, и тут должна быть выборка данных для построения маркеров на Google Maps, вот вроде все нормально, но никак не получается (из за не достатка знаний в данном направлении) сделать так что бы было как то так

```
$rows[] = $row + $numrow;
```

На выходе получаем строку `id,field,field,field ...`  а надо что бы в конце было значение этой переменной `$numrow` типа так `id,field,field,field,3`

Как правильно построить цикл ???

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

---

давно я это не пастил, забыли уже наверное.

Comment: > сделать так что бы было как то так 
> $rows[] = $row + $numrow;

Так вы практически сделали )) Только если $row массив, то надо же и $numrow массивом сделать...

    $rows[] = $row + (array)$numrow;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам похоже надо просто добавить в массив $row новый элемент $numrow, например так:

```
$row[] = $numrow; // добавиться  к элементу $row
$rows[] = $row;
```

Вообще, у вас запросы скорее всего вернут разное количество результатов, и лучше это дело организовать сразу в SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.*, c1.co  FROM users u1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as co, region FROM users GROUP BY region) as c1
ON c1.region = u1.region
ORDER BY u1.region
```

А вообще, используйте лучше [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Так, теперь уже ничего, у меня получилось вывело все строки, и каждой добавилось количество сходства поля `region`, насколько я понимаю, наверное нельзя в таком запросе что бы выводились только индивидуальныйе записи, тоесть если регион повторяется то выводится как и сейчас уже, количество сходства, но что бы сами схожие поля не выводились ?

Comment: Вроде как DISTINCT должен был предотвратить вывод похожих строк, но почему то он этого не сделал !

Comment: DISTINCT делается по всем столбцам, если вам нужно то количество, сколько регионов, тогда можете сделать RIGHT JOIN.

или вы можете поменять их местами (т.е. селектить count) и к нему добавлять по RIGHT или LEFT JOIN остальные поля (тут уже без DISTINCT)

что-то вроде этого:

    SELECT u1.*, c1.co FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as co, region FROM users GROUP BY region) c1
    LEFT JOIN users u1 ON c1.region = u1.region
    ORDER BY u1.region

Comment: Ну попробую как нибудь разобраться, хотя для меня этот sql Темный лес )

Comment: Не, так тоже самое получилось (

Comment: @Berserker с sql-ом надо разбираться ) а так, в php mysql вроде нельзя было одновременно гулять по двум выборкам. Еще как вариант (совсем уж плохой вариант) - загрузить отдельно массив кол-ва, и их дописывать к элементам из 2-ой выборки.